# Разовая перезагрузка страницы при заходе на неё

Tags: jquery

Нужно, чтобы при заходе на страничку она сразу же перезагружалась (при каждом её посещении) для изменения данных. В интернете нашел много способов перезагрузить страницу, причем как через интервал времени так и 1 раз.

Но можно ли перезагрузить страницу 1 раз после захода на нее (с помощью jquery) так, чтобы к url ничего не добавлялось?

сейчас для перезагрузки вставляю в html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) {
    window.location.replace(window.location.href+'?reload');
}
</script>
```

или такой вариант

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){   
  setTimeout(function () { 
  if(document.URL.indexOf("")==-1){
    url = document.URL+"";
    location = "";
    location.reload(true);
  }
  }, 50);
  });
</script>
```

Есть ли более "хорошие", надежные способы без всего лишнего? Ибо эти какие то..корявые, что ли. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: для изменения данных не нужно перезагружать страницу.

Comment: @ArchDemon Если я авторизовываюсь, перехожу и на другую ссылку сайта (на которой условие на php) то нет изменений, если я зайду на нее и перезагружу - то появятся. Я же хочу, чтобы не нужно было обновлять её.

Comment: У вас проблемы с логикой. Если требуется перезагрузка, значит что-то не так

Answer (score 1):

```
if (localStorage.getItem("reload") === "false") {
  localStorage.removeItem("reload");
} else {
  localStorage.setItem("reload", "false");
  window.location = window.location;
}
```